# List of favorite articles based on number of visitors

Tags: views

I am working at a magazine type web project. I would like if someone would suggest me a way to display in a block the list of favorite articles based on numbers of visitors.

I assume views can do that but I need a counter for visitors who access the articles.

Thank you. Any idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the module list, you've a module named Statistic enable it and you'll have a block that show the articles most visited in the past 7 days or 24 hours.

Also, with Views you'll able to create blocks/pages as you want.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me a clue, Statistics store the node counters in the node_counter table.
The problem with these statistics is that they also include views by admins and the author of the nodes, so it's not very accurate. Also, even if you aren't the admin or node author, if you go to a page and keep reloading the page, the node count keeps incrementing.

Comment: You will never find the perfect service for that. I mean you've always a possibility to manipulate de statistics. You just have to trust about this and wish that your visitors and author are not enough stupid to waste time for that. But if you're using Drupal 6, you can still install it. http://drupal.org/project/statistics_advanced